# Performance Counter shows different values when ReadOnly=false

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, performancecounter

I was trying to figure out why certain performance counters aren't updated in our production server, when I've hit this weird issue - the counter seems to return different `RawValue` values when it is not read only. When read-only it is always zero, when not read-only it shows different values.

Here is my PowerShell session showing this:

```
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter = new-object Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter.CategoryName = "My category"
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter.CounterName = "My counter name"
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter.ReadOnly = 1
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter


CategoryName     : My category
CounterHelp      : My counter name
CounterName      : My counter name
CounterType      : NumberOfItems64
InstanceLifetime : Global
InstanceName     :
ReadOnly         : True
MachineName      : .
RawValue         : 0
Site             :
Container        :



PS C:\Users\doron> $counter.ReadOnly = 0
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter


CategoryName     : My category
CounterHelp      : My counter name
CounterName      : My counter name
CounterType      : NumberOfItems64
InstanceLifetime : Global
InstanceName     :
ReadOnly         : False
MachineName      : .
RawValue         : 20
Site             :
Container        :



PS C:\Users\doron> $counter.ReadOnly = 1
PS C:\Users\doron> $counter


CategoryName     : My category
CounterHelp      : My counter name
CounterName      : My counter name
CounterType      : NumberOfItems64
InstanceLifetime : Global
InstanceName     :
ReadOnly         : True
MachineName      : .
RawValue         : 0
Site             :
Container        :
```

The server is Windows 2008 R2, running .NET 4.5.

An important note is that all my other performance counters are not behaving like this, only some recently added performance counters (these are the ones that don't work). For all the other counters, the RawValue id always identical, whether ReadOnly or not.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: can you give more information how do you get $counter value in the first place.

Comment: I added it in the beginning

Comment: @DoronYaacoby, Did you find any solution to this problem? I have *exactly* the same problem and would greatly appreciate any information that could lead to a solution. Please ...

Comment: @DoronYaacoby, Sorry to ask again, but in case you fixed this problem, what was the solution? If you don't want to reply on SO, please contact me on dnovatchev at gmail dot com

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev sorry, but no, I never solved it. We ended up ditching custom performance counters all together.

Answer (score 5):

Since you did not provide a lot of information on how you create the performance counter and who updates the counter at what point, I can only make an informed guess and tell you the difference between the two.

**Difference of `RawValue` when `ReadOnly=True` vs `Readonly=False`**

According to MSDN:

> If the counter that you are reading is read-only, getting the RawValue property samples the counter at the time that the property is called.This action is equivalent to making an initial call to the NextSample method.

**Source:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.rawvalue.aspx

Indeed you can confirm this looking at the actual framework source for the RawValue property:

```
public long RawValue
{
  get
  {
    if (this.ReadOnly)
      return this.NextSample().RawValue;
    this.Initialize();
    return this.sharedCounter.Value;
  }
  ...
}
```

MSDN does not say what happens when `ReadOnly` is set to `False`, however looking at the code snippet above you will see that it will call `Initialize` and then return the value of an internal `sharedCounter` object, which is created by `Initialize`. `Initialize` is called in various places though and only the first call will really initialize the object.

Because the code is quite complex, I did not understand the complete process, but it seems that the value will be cached when the performance counter is not readonly and so you will see an old value.

**Possible explanation**

I have to guess here, because you did not say how you did the test actually, but if you initialize the performance counter before you updated any value, then I would assume that you see a RawValue of 0 everytime, even if the counter is updated in the meantime.

Now as soon as you set ReadOnly to True and query RawValue again, you will see the actual value that the PerformanceCounter has at this moment.

An interesting experiment would be to call `NextSample()` instead of using `RawValue`. In my opinion you should get the same results in both cases then.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The counter was already initialized and written to when I attempted to read its value via PowerShell. Also, most of my counters DO work, only a couple of newly added ones are behaving strangely.

Comment: Can you provide more information? How to you create the counter object? How do you write/update the counter? The question was what the difference between read only and not read only is for RawValue. I looked at the actual code and came up with this. This is the only difference. If it's not the problem, then you are probably looking in the wrong place. Try to reproduce the problem in a small sample project. Also did you try NextSample? Does the counter work as expected with ReadOnly=True.

Comment: There is nothing interesting about the way the performance counter is created. It is completely standard - I create a CounterCreationData object, which is added to a PerformanceCounterCollection, which is then used to call PerformanceCounterCategory.Create.

Comment: $counter.NextSample() produces 0 whether the counter is ReadOnly or not. And no, the counter does not work as expected, it will stay on 0 no matter how much I increment it. This would not reproduce in a sample project, something is wrong with this specific counter and I'm trying to understand what.

Comment: I am sorry I can't be more helpful :-( Instead of doing a sample project, maybe you can reduce the actual project more and more until you have the minimum version where the error still occurs. Other than that there is not a lot which really differentiates the counters... If using the same counter in a sample project does not reproduce the issue, then I think the problem is not with the counter, but with the application. Did you set a breakpoint, added logging to make sure that the performance counter is really written to? Is this reproducible in another computer?

Comment: Are you experiencing other issues in the application? Do you use any unmanaged/native code which could cause memory corruption?

Comment: @aKzenT, Did you find any solution to this problem? I have exactly the same problem and would greatly appreciate any information that could lead to a solution. Please ...